# How do I quickly find a row in a sqlite database that is closest to a given input?

Tags: python, performance, sqlite, optimization

I have a function that accesses my Sqlite database that has on the order of 100,000's of rows in 100's of tables. (Database file size is about 2-3gb) I'm trying to give my function a timepoint, and I want it to return the row that has the closest timepoint to the given. The way I have it set up now, I have to run this function millions of times and I've found that the query is about 30-35ms long to run. I need to speed this up significantly, can someone suggest some fixes?

Things I have tried: 
If I remove the "ORDER BY" part of the query, it speeds up by almost an order of magnitude, but I'm not sure how to get the closest timepoint without it. I've tried loading the database into memory, but that actually made it slower with the additional time it took to load my database into memory. I've parallelized the calls over 44 processes but it takes kind of a long time to set up the processes (copying variables to memory?) but more importantly, only ~8 processes are working 100% and it's still too slow.

I do have the database indexed for the _timestamp column only.

Does any one know of a way I can bypass my whole problem, reorganize my database, change my query, come up with a better way of searching in or outside of a database, or even help me identify what's the limiting factor? I'm working on a 24 core/48 thread server with ~140GB ram.

```
def getClosestRow(conn, table, timepoint):
    query = "SELECT * FROM "+str(table)+" ORDER BY ABS("+str(timepoint)+" - _timestamp) LIMIT 1"

    result = conn.execute(query)

    for x in result: 
        return x

    return None
```

Here is the function I used to index the database:

```
def indexAllTablesWithColumn(conn, column):
    tableList = getListOfTablesInDatabase(conn)
    for tableName in tableList:
        command = "CREATE INDEX idx_"+column+tableName+" ON "+tableName+"("+column+");"
        results = conn.execute(command)
    conn.commit()
```

I did the sqlite3 database.db .schema > schema.sql suggestion and got a huge output. I'll put the head and tail here, since everything in the middle seems to just be the various tables with different names. The database contains scraped cryptocurrency data, each table is a different "coin", each column is a different feature, and each row is a different timepoint.

```sql
Head: 
CREATE TABLE _BTC_BITCOIN(id integer PRIMARY KEY,_timestamp TEXT,_24h_volume_usd REAL,_available_supply REAL,_id TEXT,_last_updated INTEGER,_market_cap_usd INTEGER,_max_supply REAL,_name TEXT,_percent_change_1h REAL,_percent_change_24h REAL,_percent_change_7d REAL,_price_btc REAL,_price_usd REAL,_rank INTEGER,_symbol TEXT,_total_supply REAL);
CREATE TABLE _ETH_ETHEREUM(id integer PRIMARY KEY,_timestamp TEXT,_24h_volume_usd REAL,_available_supply REAL,_id TEXT,_last_updated INTEGER,_market_cap_usd INTEGER,_max_supply REAL,_name TEXT,_percent_change_1h REAL,_percent_change_24h REAL,_percent_change_7d REAL,_price_btc REAL,_price_usd REAL,_rank INTEGER,_symbol TEXT,_total_supply REAL);
CREATE TABLE _XRP_RIPPLE(id integer PRIMARY KEY,_timestamp TEXT,_24h_volume_usd REAL,_available_supply REAL,_id TEXT,_last_updated INTEGER,_market_cap_usd INTEGER,_max_supply REAL,_name TEXT,_percent_change_1h REAL,_percent_change_24h REAL,_percent_change_7d REAL,_price_btc REAL,_price_usd REAL,_rank INTEGER,_symbol TEXT,_total_supply REAL);
CREATE TABLE _BCH_BITCOIN_CASH(id integer PRIMARY KEY,_timestamp TEXT,_24h_volume_usd REAL,_available_supply REAL,_id TEXT,_last_updated INTEGER,_market_cap_usd INTEGER,_max_supply REAL,_name TEXT,_percent_change_1h REAL,_percent_change_24h REAL,_percent_change_7d REAL,_price_btc REAL,_price_usd REAL,_rank INTEGER,_symbol TEXT,_total_supply REAL);
CREATE TABLE _LTC_LITECOIN(id integer PRIMARY KEY,_timestamp TEXT,_24h_volume_usd REAL,_available_supply REAL,_id TEXT,_last_updated INTEGER,_market_cap_usd INTEGER,_max_supply REAL,_name TEXT,_percent_change_1h REAL,_percent_change_24h REAL,_percent_change_7d REAL,_price_btc REAL,_price_usd REAL,_rank INTEGER,_symbol TEXT,_total_supply REAL);
CREATE TABLE _ADA_CARDANO(id integer PRIMARY KEY,_timestamp TEXT,_24h_volume_usd REAL,_available_supply REAL,_id TEXT,_last_updated INTEGER,_market_cap_usd INTEGER,_max_supply REAL,_name TEXT,_percent_change_1h REAL,_percent_change_24h REAL,_percent_change_7d REAL,_price_btc REAL,_price_usd REAL,_rank INTEGER,_symbol TEXT,_total_supply REAL);
CREATE TABLE _NEO_NEO(id integer PRIMARY KEY,_timestamp TEXT,_24h_volume_usd REAL,_available_supply REAL,_id TEXT,_last_updated INTEGER,_market_cap_usd INTEGER,_max_supply REAL,_name TEXT,_percent_change_1h REAL,_percent_change_24h REAL,_percent_change_7d REAL,_price_btc REAL,_price_usd REAL,_rank INTEGER,_symbol TEXT,_total_supply REAL);
CREATE TABLE _XLM_STELLAR(id integer PRIMARY KEY,_timestamp TEXT,_24h_volume_usd REAL,_available_supply REAL,_id TEXT,_last_updated INTEGER,_market_cap_usd INTEGER,_max_supply REAL,_name TEXT,_percent_change_1h REAL,_percent_change_24h REAL,_percent_change_7d REAL,_price_btc REAL,_price_usd REAL,_rank INTEGER,_symbol TEXT,_total_supply REAL);
CREATE TABLE _XMR_MONERO(id integer PRIMARY KEY,_timestamp TEXT,_24h_volume_usd REAL,_available_supply REAL,_id TEXT,_last_updated INTEGER,_market_cap_usd INTEGER,_max_supply REAL,_name TEXT,_percent_change_1h REAL,_percent_change_24h REAL,_percent_change_7d REAL,_price_btc REAL,_price_usd REAL,_rank INTEGER,_symbol TEXT,_total_supply REAL);
CREATE TABLE _EOS_EOS(id integer PRIMARY KEY,_timestamp TEXT,_24h_volume_usd REAL,_available_supply REAL,_id TEXT,_last_updated INTEGER,_market_cap_usd INTEGER,_max_supply REAL,_name TEXT,_percent_change_1h REAL,_percent_change_24h REAL,_percent_change_7d REAL,_price_btc REAL,_price_usd REAL,_rank INTEGER,_symbol TEXT,_total_supply REAL);

Tail: 
CREATE INDEX idx__timestamp_VZT_VEZT ON _VZT_VEZT(_timestamp);
CREATE INDEX idx__timestamp_SKB_SAKURA_BLOOM ON _SKB_SAKURA_BLOOM(_timestamp);
CREATE INDEX idx__timestamp_FID_FIDELIUM ON _FID_FIDELIUM(_timestamp);
CREATE INDEX idx__timestamp_MOAC_MOAC ON _MOAC_MOAC(_timestamp);
CREATE INDEX idx__timestamp_NKN_NKN ON _NKN_NKN(_timestamp);
CREATE INDEX idx__timestamp_CLO_CALLISTO_NETWORK ON _CLO_CALLISTO_NETWORK(_timestamp);
CREATE INDEX idx__timestamp_SWTH_SWITCHEO ON _SWTH_SWITCHEO(_timestamp);
CREATE INDEX idx__timestamp_TUBE_BITTUBE ON _TUBE_BITTUBE(_timestamp);
CREATE INDEX idx__timestamp_BETR_BETTERBETTING ON _BETR_BETTERBETTING(_timestamp);
CREATE INDEX idx__timestamp_LYL_LOYALCOIN ON _LYL_LOYALCOIN(_timestamp);
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on all relevant columns of all relevant tables?

Comment: Export the schema of your sqlite db and show here the structure of the table you're querying: `sqlite3 test.db .schema > schema.sql`

Comment: maybe do an explain to know if index is being used

Comment: Hi all, thanks for all the comments. I've included the function I used to index the database, as well as the head and tail portions of the schema.sql suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY ABS(? - _timestamp)
LIMIT 1;
```

This query is simple and correct, but it is not possible to optimize the lookup with an index. (Not even with an [expression index](http://www.sqlite.org/expridx.html), because the function parameter changes, so the result cannot be stored.)

You get a fast query if you compute something else: the nearest row that is at or later than the timestamp:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE _timestamp >= ?
ORDER BY _timestamp
LIMIT 1;
```

To get the correct result, compute the nearest two rows *before* and *after* then timestamp, and then take the row with the smallest difference (sorting two rows is fast):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE _timestamp >= ?
      ORDER BY _timestamp ASC
      LIMIT 1)

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE _timestamp <= ?
      ORDER BY _timestamp DESC
      LIMIT 1)

ORDER BY ABS(? - _timestamp)
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! Such a simple idea that I couldn't manage to think up on my own, haha. Just the first suggestion of only checking in one direction first cut down my time from 90 minutes to about 40, which I think will be good enough for my application. :)